# EJB Core Contracts and Requirements - v3.1 (JSR-318 - 2009) to v3.2 (JSR-345 - 2013) Programming Restrictions Change

Tags: java, ejb, classloader, jsr

In section 21.2.2 Programming Restrictions of JSR-318 there is text as follows

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to create a class loader; **obtain the current class loader**; set the context class loader; set security manager; create a new security manager; stop the JVM; or change the input, output, and error streams.

But in JSR-345 Section 16.2.2 Programming Restrictions, that same text is now:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to create a class loader; set the context class loader; set
>   security manager; create a new security manager; stop the JVM; or change the input, output,
>   and error streams

I was attempting to explain this to someone, and wanted to pull up the JSR, for reference, via a web search and was puzzled when what I was reading wasn't as I remembered.

My question is, does anyone have any insight into why this language changed? Why this now implies that it's OK to obtain the classloader (so long as you don't violate other Reflection API changes that still exist in section 16.2.2 of JSR-345)?